# System freezes when paging. Any way to warn in advace?

Tags: virtual-memory

I often use my laptop with a lot of tabs open, plus some other memory heavy applications such as Pycharm. It happens maybe once a day when I am working that I open a new tab and the system freezes as it starts paging.

Is there a way to warn me when the memory is full enough that it warns before it starts paging so I can close some tabs / applications in advance? Or is there any other way of getting around this problem?

Comment: You can add a memory usage graph in the desktop panel.

Comment: Install and enable `earlyoom`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [nohang](https://github.com/hakavlad/nohang).  It has GUI notifications and can warn about low memory conditions, and it also will kill processes before you get in the situation where the system hangs.